# sp_spaceused on SQL 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am unfamiliar with the results returned by the `sp_spaceused` procedure on SQL server 2008.

Please see the output below:

[image]

and

[image]

Am I correct in reading this as there are 38.2 gigs of available space left on this database? Or is in 116.6 gigs?

Comment: What does the manual say?

Answer (score 0):

**unallocated space**-**varchar(18)**: Space in the database that has not been reserved for database objects.

**unused**-**varchar(18)**: Total amount of space reserved for objects in the database, but not yet used.

> database_size will always be larger than the sum of reserved + unallocated space because it includes the size of log files, but reserved and unallocated_space consider only data pages.
>
> Pages that are used by XML indexes and full-text indexes are included in index_size for both result sets. When objname is specified, the pages for the XML indexes and full-text indexes for the object are also counted in the total reserved and index_size results.
>
> If space usage is calculated for a database or an object that has a spatial index, the space-size columns, such as database_size, reserved, and index_size, include the size of the spatial index.

[Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188776.aspx)

[Comments on SP_SPACEUSED:](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1805/different-ways-to-determine-free-space-for-sql-server-databases-and-database-files/)

> we can see how much free space there is in the database, but this shows us total free space including the transaction log free space which may be totally misleading.

I recommend for you:

> Using FILEPROPERTY to check for free space in a database
> Another option is to use the SpaceUsed property of the FILEPROPERTY function which will tell us how much space is used and then we can calculate free space based on the current size and what is being used.

```
USE Test5 
GO 

SELECT DB_NAME() AS DbName, 
name AS FileName, 
size/128.0 AS CurrentSizeMB, 
size/128.0 - CAST(FILEPROPERTY(name, 'SpaceUsed') AS INT)/128.0 AS FreeSpaceMB 
FROM sys.database_files;
```

[Source](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1805/different-ways-to-determine-free-space-for-sql-server-databases-and-database-files/)